# search web doc in browser by Ctrl-F, if the result is a link, how to open it directly from keyboard rather than use mouse

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, find, keyboard-shortcuts

I find that it is low efficient to locate a term, which might be a link, and then click to open it. Try to imagine we located the link then use keyboard open it directly. Are there any similar built-in features in mainstream browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by hitting [`esc`] and hitting [`enter`].